# AutoIt script not working for file upload,

Tags: file-upload, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I have written following AutoIT script after reading few blogs, my main requirement is to enter the file name to be uploaded in the upload box

```
WinWaitActive("Choose files","",10)
ControlFocus("Choose files","","Edit1")
Sleep(2000)
ControlSetText("Choose files","","Edit1","dropdowns.jpg")
```

My code does not give any error but does not run the script or no action takes place. My script calling code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/bhavneet.singh/Downloads/scrip1.exe");
```

Note: I took Basic control info by default as no information was getting loaded for the window pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
#RequireAdmin ;Will give your script a permission elevation (sometimes its needed)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 1) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also

WinWaitActive("Choose file","",10)
ControlFocus("Choose file","","Edit1")
Sleep(2000)
ControlSetText("Choose file","","Edit1","dropdowns.jpg")
```

Comment: it didn't work :( Though I don't get any error in my script. Any way to check if my script is even getting called properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine: just check if you have compiled your autoit script correctly.
I used similar code and it was not working, then I realized I compiled it incorrectly: Mine was 32 bits but I compiled to x64; when I changed to x86, it worked.